# Get VMs Created in Last 10 Minutes

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I'm trying to get a script together which isolates VMs created in the last 10 minutes, but I keep getting the same results even if the vm was created an hour ago even if I specify 10 minutes.

The code I use:

```
$VMObject = get-azvm -ResourceGroupName "vmtest"

foreach ($VM in $VMObject)
{
       
            $VMDiskName = $VM.StorageProfile.OsDisk.Name
 
           
            $VMDiskInfo = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $VMDiskName

            $minutes = 10

            $VMCreatedDate = $VMDiskInfo.TimeCreated
            $time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-$minutes)
            if ($VMCreatedDate -lt $time)
            {
                Write-Output $vm.name "Created $VMCreatedDate"
            }
            elseif ($VMCreatedDate -gt $time)
            {
                Write-Output $vm.name "out of range Created $VMCreatedDate" 
            }
       }
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I think I'm doing get the vms where time created was less than 10 minutes ago. I think.

Comment: The logic looks ok, can you show us the output of ```$VMCreatedDate``` in each iteration?

Comment: Try to swap the comparison to: `$time -gt $VMCreatedDate`. Based on the LHS, that will force a datetime comparison.

Comment: Thanks all, @iRon that seems to have done the trick, but all time is showing in UTC, is there a way to change all time to reference BST (Ritish summer time), as the timing is showing an hour out

Comment: The `datetime struct` has methods as [`ToUniversalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime) and [`ToLocalTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime).